# Can we add nuget package specific to a targetframework

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-6.0, .net-8.0

I am building a common library targeted for both net462 and net6.0. As part of this project, I want to add `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` nuget package for net462 and `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core` for net6.0. I am trying to do take the below approach but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net462'">
    <PackageReference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: What *exactly* happens? "Doesn't seem to work" isn't very informative.

Comment: fundamentally, what you are doing should work fine (assuming you're using central package management) - it is exactly what I'm doing [here](https://github.com/DapperLib/DapperAOT/blob/930027039c4591e3b64065c9601a13ca9655c53b/test/Dapper.AOT.Test/Dapper.AOT.Test.csproj#L37-L38) (the `Condition` can be per-item or per-group); so: can you please give a *verbatim* account of what happens? the exact error message, etc?

Comment: Could be some issue with nuget cache, I have cleaned up everything and it has started working fine now. thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to specify the appropriate versions for each package.

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net462'">
    <PackageReference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" Version="21.13.0" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core" Version="3.21.130" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I think we can *reasonably* assume that OP is using central package management, in which case it is not only *unnecessary* but *disallowed* to specify `Version` like this; IMO we should await OP's clarification on the error, but: I very much doubt that this is it

Comment: Yeah I am using central package management, this isn't issue. I worked my way and working now, could be some issue with nuget cache, I have cleaned up everything and it has started working fine now. thanks guys.